# Crear enlace en fila de columna de una tabla html con php

Tags: php, javascript, html

He creado esta tabla en la que se me muestran datos de una base de datos, y necesito enlazar la tabla con la página de detalles, pero no soy capaz de hacerlo.

La idea es que pulsando en cualquier parte de cada fila de tabla te lleve a la página `details.php?ID=code`, dónde `code` es un elemento de cada entrada en la base de datos.

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
$sql="SELECT * from comp";
$result=mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<html>
<div class="table-wrapper">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="table100-head">
                        <th class="column1"> </th>
                        <th class="column2" colspan="2">Código</th>
                        <th class="column3" colspan="2">Competición</th>
                        <th class="column4">Organizador</th>
                        <th class="column5" colspan="2">Localización</th>
                        <th class="column6">Fecha</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="cursor-pointer " onclick = "window.open(<?php echo "<a href = 'details.php?ID={$mostrar['code']}'</a>" ?> " title="">
                        <td class="column1"></td>
                        <td class="column2"><?php echo "{$mostrar['code']}" ?></td>
                        <td class="column3"><?php echo "{$mostrar['nombre']}" ?></td>
                        <td class="column4"><?php echo "{$mostrar['Organizador']}" ?></td>
                        <td class="column5"><?php echo "{$mostrar['Ubicacion']}" ?></td>
                        <td class="column6"><?php echo "{$mostrar['Fecha']}" ?></td>
                    </tbody>
</html>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Consulta, estas usando dataTables?

Comment: No estoy usando datatables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open) recibe como primer parámetro una cadena, pero vos estas imprimiendo tag `<a>`, lo cual provoca un error de sintaxis.

#### Solución:

- Si necesitas que se abra en una ventana nueva:

  ```
    <tr class="cursor-pointer" onclick="window.open('details.php?ID=<?php echo $mostrar['code']; ?>')" title="">
  ```
- Si necesitas que se abra en la misma ventana:

  ```
    <tr class="cursor-pointer" onclick="window.location.href='details.php?ID=<?php echo $mostrar['code']; ?>'" title="">
  ```